# Gaps in the proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I found a very short *formal* proof of the infinite partial fraction expansion of $\cot x$:
$$\cot x = \sum_{k \in \mathbb Z} \frac{1}{x - k\pi} = \frac{1}{x} + \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{x + k\pi} + \frac{1}{x - k\pi} \right),
\quad x \in \mathbb R \setminus \pi \mathbb Z.$$
I would like to know how this proof can be rendered rigorous (using only elementary arguments and results). Here is the proof:

**Proof**: Suppose $\cot x$ has a series expansion of the form
$$\cot x = \sum_{k \in \mathbb Z} \frac{c_k}{x - k\pi},$$
where the coefficients $c_k$ are yet to be determined. Now, multiply both sides by $x$ and let $x \to 0$. This yields $c_0 = \lim_{x \to 0} x \cot x = 1$. Furthermore, one can show that, in general, $c_k = \lim_{x \to \pm k\pi} (x \mp k\pi) \cot x = 1$ for $k \in \mathbb Z_{\geq 0}$. Hence
$$\cot x = \sum_{k \in \mathbb Z} \frac{1}{x - k\pi},$$
which is the result sought. **Q.E.D.**

Of particular interest is the fact that this method can be used to derive other infinite partial fraction expansions of some trigonometric functions.

I think we can invoke the classical Tannery's theorem for series to interchange limit and infinite summation.

However, does the initial supposition, namely, $\cot x = \sum_{k \in \mathbb Z} c_k/(x - k\pi)$, need any justification? Is it not the same method we use to determine the Taylor (and/or Fourier) series coefficients, for instance? It seems like if it were not true, then I would get a contradiction, e.g., if $\sin x = \sum_{k \in \mathbb Z} c_k/(x - k\pi)$, then $\sin x = 0$, which is absurd. Do I need to consider a partial sum instead?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One way to rigorize this proof is to use the [Liouville theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29). Let $S(x)$ denote the series representation and let $f(x) = \cot x$. Then, one checks that the function $g = f / S $ is entire (i.e. analytic in the whole plane) and bounded. These hypotheses imply, by the Liouville theorem, that $g$ is a constant, and since $f(0) = S(0)$, that constant is equal to 1.

There is another consideration: one does have to show that the series representation $S$ actually converges uniformly on compact sets, so that $S$ is a well-defined and analytic function on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \pi \mathbb{Z}$. This can be done, for e.g., by observing that
$$
S(x) = \frac{1}{x} + \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{2 x}{x^2 - \pi^2 k^2}
$$

Comment: Thanks. I think you misunderstood my question. An application of Liouville's theorem is a standard proof of the infinite partial fraction expansion of $\cot x$, which differs from my proof. I want to rigorize the proof I presented (using only elementary arguments).

Comment: By the way, what exactly is $f(0)$? Do you mean $f(0) = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \cot x = \infty$?